# Timeout exception when querying view by DBML

Tags: sql, linq

Using Visual Studio 2010 and DBML, I created small application that deals with SQL 2008 database. The database contains some views and procedures, all of them working fine with`LINQ except only one view. Please see the following code:

```
public vw_SubmissionCurrentStepInfo GetSubmissionCurrentStepInfo(int SubmissionID, int StepID)
{
    return 
        db
        .vw_SubmissionCurrentStepInfos
        .Where(entity => entity.SubmissionID == SubmissionID && entity.StepID == StepID)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It throws the following exception

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

but it works fine when adding `.ToList()` to code like that:

```
return 
    db
    .vw_SubmissionCurrentStepInfos
    .Where(entity => entity.SubmissionID == SubmissionID && entity.StepID == StepID)
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note I increased the `connection string timeout` with no effect.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Server Profiler to take a look at the query that was generated?

Comment: it is normal query like the following,

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Column1], [t0].[Column2],........ 
FROM [dbo].[vw_SubmissionCurrentStepInfo] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[SubmissionID] = 9573) AND ([t0].[StepID] = 37);